# Gravity Forms Dropdown List Display

Tags: forms, dropdown, number-formatting, gravity

I created a dropdown list of time - 1 min to 60 mins. When it displays, it is not in sequential order but places all the "1's" together (ie: 1,12,19), then the twos, and so forth. I need it to be 1 through 60. What do I need to include?

I'm a newbie in code but I did try looking for a style command or custom css class for sequential with no luck.

Comment: How are you adding these choices? I assume not manually or you could just sort them manually.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the dropdown list displays the numbers 1 through 60 in sequential order, you can try adding custom JavaScript code to sort the options alphabetically. Here's a simple example of how you can achieve this using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var dropdown = $('#dropdown-id');
    
    var options = dropdown.find('option');
    
    options.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(a).text()) - parseInt($(b).text());
    });
    
    dropdown.html(options);
});
```